# How can I get data from a specific cell in an HTML table in python?

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

[This link contains the table I'm trying to parse.](http://www.blackbeltsystem.com/BBS_student_grads.php#anchor)
I'm trying to use `BeautifulSoup` in Python. I'm very new to `BeautifulSoup` and HTML. This is my attempt to solve my problem.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(open('BBS_student_grads.php'))

data = []
table = soup.find('table')
rows = table.find_all('tr') #array of rows in table 

for x,row in enumerate(rows[1:]):# skips first row 
    cols = row.find_all('td')    # finds all cols in rows
    for y,col in enumerate(cols): # iterates through col
        data.append([])
        data[x].append(col)       # puts table into a 2d array called data

print(data[0][0])                 #prints top left corner
```

[Sample Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yc2Ue.png)

I'm trying to extract all the names in the table, then update the names in the list and then update the table. I'm also using a local copy of this HTML. Temporary fix till I learn how to do more web programming.

help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need just the `td` elements in the `tr` element with `class="searchbox_black"`.

You can use [`CSS Selectors`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) to get to the desired `td` elements:

```
for cell in soup.select('tr.searchbox_black td'):
    print cell.text
```

It prints:

```
BB Salsa

 Adams State University Alamosa, CO               
              Sensei: Oneyda Maestas               
              Raymond Breitstein               

...
```

Comment: for some reason when you go further down when it starts printing spaces between every character.   Actual output: "Rebecca Ha   l   l   b   r   &gt; "

Comment: @thor sorry, cannot reproduce it, what is your current code? Thanks.

Comment: `soup = BeautifulSoup(open('BBS_student_grads.php'))
    data = []
for cell in soup.select('tr.searchbox_black td'):                           data.append(cell)

print(data[0])`  @alecxe

Comment: @thor did you mean `data.append(cell.text)` instead?

Comment: cell.text does output just the text but it still does some odd formatting around "Rebecca Hall". python puts 3 space around every character